# How do I remove all instances of a key from a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I've got a Java Script object like this:

```
let obj = {
    selected; true,
    level1: {
        level2: {
            selected: true
        }
    }
    level1: {
        selected: true,
        level2:{}
    }
};
```

I want to remove all instances of 'selected: true'. How can I do this?
I need to solution to be generic because I may never know which level it is on.

I previously tried to look at the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library but the omit function doesn't go deep.

```
_.omit(obj, ['selected']);
// → no change
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it recursively, something like this:

```
 function removeProp(obj, propToDelete) {
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
        removeProp(obj[property], propToDelete);
      } else {
        if (property === propToDelete && obj[property] === true) {
          delete obj[property];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6bwuq9wk/6/

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I wasn't the down voter, off topic questions happen a lot here. Trying to answer them only encourages the behavior. Recommended reading: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/848058)

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Thanks, I'll keep it in mind next time.

Comment: The solution works great expect for the case where there are duplicate sub-objects like 2 level1's. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That's not possible since the object keys are unique, meaning a key can hold only one value. If you like to hold multiple value, then you assign array value to it. like { key : [value1, value2 ...]}